# SSRS 2008 Hidden Columns Should NOT Export to CSV

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

When I hide columns in SSRS they still appear in the CSV export.

I have to hide columns, not the entire tablix.

This is what I have tried already:
The filters in the tablix hide rows not columns.
The DataElementOutput per column can not be set using an expression.

Comment: This appears to still be a problem in SSRS 2106...

Answer (score 9):

Format options such as expressions on visibility are ignored for CSV rendering methods. CSV rendering methods are essentially data flows, so you can suppress elements that you don't want to include in CSV files by changing the DataElementOutput from Auto, the default value, to NoOutput.

Comment: this DataElementOutput is the thing we shud be altering to NoOutput. Nice one.

Comment: As I understand using DataElementOutput property we can statically show or hide column(s) for CSV. But how to do this dynamically, based on expression?

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution in the version of SRS 2008 R2, you need to perform a hide fields as follows:

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="CSV", True, False)
```

means this part of the "Globals!RenderFormat.Name" is crucial

Comment: This piece of code is placed in the hidden property of field, and when the report is run, if he chooses format "CSV" output, this piece of code will hide the field.