# Hide fields in SSRS report based on expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

i have one problem with exporting to CSV format. In my report i user parameter to hide on field and it's working ok except for exporting in CSV format.
Column visibility is see like this:

```
=IIF(Parameters!ShowBonusLockingData.Value="False",true,false)
```

but this doesn't work in CSV. Can someone help me with this problem. Setting column property to NoOutput is not a solution, because that property never shows the column then

Comment: Did you check [this](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2011/01/18/ssrs-hideshow-items-dependant-on-export-format/)? Also you might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511512/ssrs-2008-hidden-columns-should-not-export-to-csv) answer useful.

Comment: Yes but for CSV that doesn't work. So i need some workaround to manipulate csv export with selected parameter

Comment: =IIf(Globals!RenderFormat.Name Like "EXCELOPENXML*", False, True) That's  to only show on export to excel. Just find the one for CSV.

Comment: Ok but how to combine that with upper parameter ShowbonusLockingData? I must hide field with parameter

Comment: Something like this:  `=iif(Parameter.ShowBonusLockingData.Value = "True" and Globals!RenderFormat.Name Like "CSV", true,false)`.

Comment: Why not just control the column in the expression instead of in the visibility? i.e.  IIF(Parameters!ShowBonusLockingData.Value="False","",Fields!BonusLocking.Value)? This hides it in the CSV